# How to input values into multiline string dynamically in python based on loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, multilinestring

I am trying to pass values into the multi line string per the application value present in input json. Printing the block per application with the values parsed from json.

```
  block = """
  {app} <<
  {default1};
  {default2};

  server_name {servername1};
  server_name {servername2};

  location {location}
  ^
  proxy_pass http://{application};

  allow {filter1};
  allow {filter2};
  $
  >>"""
```

Adding block per app as per below

```
  all += '\n' + block.format(**sub).replace('<<', '{').replace('^','{').replace('$','}').replace('>>', '}')
```

i have saved the values that needs to be passed in sub.

Now in case of location variable within block - this value is changing per app. For one application there is only one location however for other there are two values. I am getting only the last value of location as its getting overwritten in the loop. how i can write dymacially update the location block inside the app_block

Below is how the output should be.

```
app1 {

location / {
    data
}
location /public {
    data
}

}

app2 {

location / {
    proxy_pass http://production;
}
location /secret {

}
}
```

Comment: Look into templating engines like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/)